# NPM server not starting from User Data of AWS instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I am starting an AWS EC2 [ Bitnami NodeJs Image, link below] instance with below User Data so that it automatically sets up and hosts a website on port 3000. **This user data is getting executed only partially** as the /hbfl directory is created with required repository also downloaded but the server is not yet started. If I ssh and run the last 2 commands the website is up and running [ Tested by going to public IP from another device]. I also checked by creating an instance with no user data and putting this script in a .sh file and execting at home directory, even that works. So it seems it's not an issue with the steps at least, maybe something with permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install git
git clone https://github.com/vndn/hbfl.git
cd hbfl
sudo npm i
sudo npm run start
```

Note- AMI URL- [https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZUAKO?ref=cns_1clkP](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZUAKO?ref=cns_1clkPro)ro

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running commands into specific user's directory instead of root directory? (e.g. cd /home/ubuntu)

And also use npm run start without sudo.

Secondly, the main problem I see here is: npm run start doesn't run node applications in the background. You may need to use something like nohup or pm2 (process manager 2) to resolve this issue.